# Non-HTTPS <image> in SVG not displayed in Facebook Messenger webview

Tags: android, https, facebook-messenger, messenger, facebook-messenger-bot

I have a bot which features a webview of a third-party service. That page contains an iframe with an image. The problem is, the image is not displayed properly in built-in browser in FB Messenger on Android. It does fine in Chrome though.

This is how it's supposed to look and how it looks in the browser:
[image: This is how it's supposed to look and how it looks in the browser]

This is how it actually looks:
[image: This is how it actually looks]

The SVG code is as follows:

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns:ev="http://www.w3.org/2001/xml-events" style="overflow: hidden; touch-action: none; user-select: none; -webkit-user-drag: none; -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);">
    <g id="viewport-20180627123051405" class="svg-pan-zoom_viewport" transform="matrix(0.25,0,0,0.25,0,83)" style="transform: matrix(0.25, 0, 0, 0.25, 0, 83);">
        <image xlink:href="http://armmolody.mticket.com.ua:8081/m-ticket/images/molody_id26.png" x="0" y="0" width="1200" height="812">
        </image>
        ........
    </g>
```

- It turns out that bug only reproduces if the URL to the webview/built-in browser URL is HTTPS. Apparently it's a "unsafe content" problem.

Could there be any workaround for this problem

Comment: afaik the Messenger webview won't allow you to show an iframe

Comment: It will, in fact, if all comment is https